# Retrieving an element by array index in jQuery vs the each() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was writing a "pluginable" function when I noticed the following behavior (tested in FF 3.5.9 with Firebug 1.5.3).

```
$.fn.computerMove = function () {
    var board = $(this);
    var emptySquares = board.find('div.clickable');
    var randPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * emptySquares.length);


    emptySquares.each(function (index) {
        if (index === randPosition) {
            // logs a jQuery object
            console.log($(this));
        }
    });

    target = emptySquares[randPosition];
    // logs a non-jQuery object
    console.log(target);
    // throws error: attr() not a function for target
    board.placeMark({'position' : target.attr('id')});
}
```

I noticed the problem when the script threw an error at `target.attr('id')` (`attr` not a function). When I checked the log, I noticed that the output (in Firebug) for target was:

```
<div style="width: 97px; height: 97px;" class="square clickable" id="8"></div>
```

If I output `$(target)`, or `$(this)` from the `each()` function, I get a nice jQuery object:

```
[ div#8.square ]
```

Now here comes my question: why does this happen, considering that `find()` seems to return an array of jQuery objects? Why do I have to do `$()` to `target` all over again?

```
[div#0.square, div#1.square, div#2.square, div#3.square, div#4.square, div#5.square, div#6.square, div#7.square, div#8.square]
```

Just a curiosity :).

Comment: Probably not related, but html id's are supposed to start with a-zA-Z.

Comment: Try `target = emptySquares.find(':eq(' + randPosition + ')');`

Comment: In answering the question, I forgot the how to do it part:  for this use `emptySquares.eq(randPosition)` to get a jQuery element at that position (0 based).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.find()` returns not *an array of* jQuery objects, but *one jQuery object* containing an array of DOM elements (a jQuery object, at it's core, is a wrapper around a DOM element array).

When you're iterating through, each element you're on is a DOM element.  So, it needs to be wrapped in `$(this)` to become jQuery object and have access to those methods.

Also as a side note: The `id` attribute can't begin with a number, since it's invalid HTML you may or may not experience strange behavior, especially cross-browser (this rule applies for any invalid HTML).

Comment: +1. Therefore: `document.getElementById("id");` is equivalent to `$("#id")[0];`

Answer (score 0):

No, the `find` method doesn't return an array of jQuery objects. You are creating a jQuery object for each element here:

```
console.log($(this));
```

If you log the value without creating a jQuery object from it:

```
console.log(this);
```

you will see that it's an element, not a jQuery object.

When you access the jQuery object as an array, you get an element. If you want a jQuery object you have to create one from the element.